# Passing Linq list to MVC web form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass my query result and then i want to iterate on my web form. This is my list

```
  var recentGames = game.OrderByDescending(c => c.OutcomeDateTime)
                                    .Take(3);
```

Right now i am trying to put this in ViewData

```
 ViewData["Elements"] = recentGames;
```

Then trying to loop though the ViewData["Elements"] on my View

```
 List<Games> t = (List<Games>)ViewData["Elements"];
```

recentGames has Games class attributes but i am not able to initialize Games class in my View (web form) and getting error. Is there any better way to pass list to view and then iterate through the loop to print simple???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display the properties of your collection like

```
@foreach(var item in ViewData["Elements"] as IEnumerable<Game>) {
  // Display properties of Game e.g.
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.MyProperty)
}
```

Comment: i want to print my recentGames list can you tell me how to do it? i am passing my list into my view and how can i access on view ]

Comment: Have you tried the code above (just replace "MyProperty" with the actual name of one of the properties in your `Game` class

Comment: i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `recentGames` isn't `List<Games>`. It's either `IQueryable<Games>` or `IEnumerable<Games>`, depending on the type of `game`.

A better way of putting it is that `recentGames` is not a list, it is a query.

What you need to do is add a `.ToList()` to the end of the query to turn it into a list.

Like this:

```
var recentGames =
    game
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.OutcomeDateTime)
        .Take(3)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: and then how can i print in my webform using forach loop?

Comment: @user3750312 - I'm sorry, but I'm not an MVC web developer. I just could see the issue with the casting you were trying.